# Missing wheel for et-xmlfile when creating install of python program

Tags: python, openpyxl, pynsist

I just added the ability of my python application to write a data set out to an excel file using openpyxl. Apparently openpyxl is dependent on the et-xmlfile. I create an install of my application by first running "setup.py sdist bdist_wheel" and then "pynsist installer.cfg".  I added both openpyxl==3.0.7 and et-xmlfile=1.0.1 to the [Include] section of the installer.cfg file.

When running pynsist I get the following error.

File "c:\users\vh942e\appdata\local\python\lib\site-packages\nsist\wheels.py", line 150, in get_from_pypi
raise NoWheelError('No compatible wheels found for {0.name} {0.version}'.format(self))
nsist.wheels.NoWheelError: No compatible wheels found for et-xmlfile 1.0.1

Are there any ideas about how to solve this no compatible wheels problem?  All other included libraries work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

et-xmlfile [doesn't have wheels on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/et_xmlfile/#files) and for now, Pynsist only consumes wheels someone else has buil. That may change one day, but it would be a significant extra bit of complexity.

It looks like it's a pure Python project, so it's easy to make a wheel of it yourself:

```
pip wheel -w my_wheels et_xmlfile
```

Then you can specify in the [include section of Pynsist's config file](https://pynsist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cfgfile.html#include-section):

```
 extra_wheel_sources=my_wheels/
```

Alternatively, it looks like someone made a little fork of et-xmlfile a few days ago ([et-xmlfile-2021](https://pypi.org/project/et-xmlfile-2021/#files)) and uploaded a wheel. You might be able to use that instead. Of course it's up to you to check that the fork can be trusted if you decide to use it.